# Can I send facebook message to a non friend?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, integration, chatbot

I'm looking at the "Messeger Platform API" documentation, and was not clear to me if I can use any Facebook API to:

1. Send a message from a **page** to a public profile.
2. Send a message from a facebook profile to another who **is not** my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Messenger Platform is not for user to user communcation. Read the docs to find out what it is about, and how to use it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform